# Is there a way to deploy my app on a hosted platform?

Tags: node.js, leaflet, server-side

Dear Stackoverflow people,

I am facing the following problem: 
For an internship in a company I have created a leaflet map with several custom features such as custom popups, markerstyle etc. The thing is, in the end they are supposed to manage the whole thing. Since they don´t know anything about code they asked for the easiest possible way for them to add data to the map.
So I came across the serverside tutorial by CodingTrain using Node.js and thought its perfect for me. Now I created basically a webform that takes up all information, converts it into a geoJSON feature, stores it in a database and sends it to the map to be displayed, great easy GUI to add new features...

Now comes the bummer which I didnt know would be a problem: The website is on a hosted service called Bitrix. I uploaded my project and it does not recognize the routes and cant write to the database or anything. I actually dont know whether I can run node on this platform?

I had the idea to launch the whole thing on  a Service like Heroku or Glitch and just take the map from there and include it into the other website via an Iframe or something like that. Do you guys think thats feasible? Are there any other better ways?

Sorry for my obvious cluelessness but I´m completely new to serverside programming and thought I´d found an easy way out... I am grateful for any kind of suggestions or help!

Comment: You should start by finding out what capabilities Bitrix has and how much control do you have on the server. May be you can run pm2 on that server itself ?

Comment: hm I talked to the support and they said there is no way to access the server. I even specifically asked them about node and all I get is "this feature is not available"...